# Could you please explain the words in this '一边对着双桅小帆船呶呶嘴'?

Tags: translation, meaning, vocabulary, meaning-in-context

I found this:
一边对着双桅小帆船呶呶嘴。“他帮我把船从巴拿马开过来。”
I nodded toward the ketch. " He helped me sail her up from Panama. "

What does '桅'mean here?
Does 呶呶嘴 mean 'nod'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

'桅' is short for '桅杆', which is mast. So '双桅' means two-masted. 
'呶呶嘴' literaly means 'Pout lips'(no sexual meaning here). It means instead of pointing that sailboat by hand, some one points the lips to the sailboat instead. Some time I do this kind of things when I'm being lazy or my hands are occupied.

Comment: So it means two masted...., for 呶呶嘴, i googled them and found they also mean talking incessantly... would their meaning also change depending on the context?

Comment: @Fai91 Well, according to this context,"对着" means at or toward, So I think the meaning should be pointting at the two-masked sailboat boat( not by hand but by lips)